# How to change priority of Chrome's URL autocomplete

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

Let's say I frequently visit **www.mydomain.co.uk**

Chrome quite rightly suggests this URL when I begin to type "myd"

Now, I am very often going to **www.mydomain.co.uk/directory** - Chrome presumably has recognised that recently, I visit this page more frequently than I visit **www.mydomain.co.uk**. Now when I begin typing "myd", the first URL suggested to me is **www.mydomain.co.uk/directory** with **www.mydomain.co.uk** having been pushed down the list.

I want for **www.mydomain.co.uk** to always remain at the top of the suggested list, is there a way I can manually re-order the suggestions or perhaps ensure that **www.mydomain.co.uk** is always the first suggestion?

---

I'm aware that you can delete things from the autocomplete list, that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: 2nd result from searching for your question title ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I searched, just not that precise phrase. Thanks.